# Laravel 4 - Join table but only latest row

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables : Quotes, Responses.

In a datatable , I show quotes, and for each row, I show a column count of responses. I want now to show date of latest response, but I'm blocked :(

Here is my code:

```
$quotes = Quote::select('Quotes.*', DB::raw('COUNT(Responses.id) as total_responses') )
    ->leftjoin('Responses', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('Responses.quote_id', '=', 'Quotes.id')
        ->where('Responses.state', '!=', '0');
    })
    ->groupby('Quotes.id');
```

Is it possible to add another left join with same table, with custom query to select only latest row?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you saying you need to sort by `created_at` col descending, and select first row? Or that you want to get all quotes and get the date of the last quote response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the raw `MAX` function. Assuming your date is stored `Responses.date`, the code will look like this

```
$quotes = Quote::select('Quotes.*', DB::raw('COUNT(Responses.id) as total_responses'), DB::raw('MAX(CAST(Responses.date AS CHAR)) as latest') )
    ->leftjoin('Responses', function($join) {
        $join->on('Responses.quote_id', '=', 'Quotes.id')
        ->where('Responses.state', '!=', '0');
    })
    ->groupby('Quotes.id');
```

It first has to be cast as a char because of a mysql bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784

Comment: The bug reported here is fixed in mySQL 5.6+ on 4 Aug 2010 8:23 (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49771)

So if using mySQL 5.6+ there is no need to cast the date used in MAX() or MINX() to char first.

Comment: Please also note the above answer will show the latest date as requested in the question, but not the latest row, as requested in the title of the question.

The difference is important.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to include `Responses.created_at` in your select command and filter it using same column. i.e.

```
$quotes = Quote::select('Quotes.*', 'Responses.created_at as last_response_date', DB::raw('COUNT(Responses.id) as total_responses'))
    ->leftjoin('Responses', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('Responses.quote_id', '=', 'Quotes.id')
        ->where('Responses.state', '!=', '0');
    })
    ->groupby('Quotes.id')->orderBy('Responses.created_at', 'desc');
```